# How call a javascript function from .NET Core 2 backend?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a react-redux application with .NET Core 2 backend. 
I want from my controller:

```
public void Show([FromQuery] string id)
{
    // do some code
    // here I need to call a javascript function        
}
```

call a javascript function that e.g. alert a message:

```
function showAlert() {
   alert('Warning!');
}
```

I am searching for something similar to ASP.NET *Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript*. I need something simple as that. Is there anything?

Comment: ASP.NET Core runs on the server. JavaScript runs on the client. You can't run JS from the server. (At least not in the way you're attempting. You can run JS via Node, but that's just server-side as well. You can't make anything happen on the client.)

Comment: If you want to execute JavaScript after some .NET code has run you do it on the return of the request to the front end. So in order to execute code on the server side, the client side will make a request. The request has to finish (known as the response), when this is sent back to the client side you now have a chance to execute some JavaScript in response...